# If I use Cloudflare, will it unblock countries?

Tags: cloudflare

I have a website and I blocked 3 countries visitors using htaccess. I need to use Cloudflare at this moment. But I don't want those 3 countries to visit my website anymore. If I use Cloudflare, will it unblock those 3 countries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your .htaccess configuration probably uses the source IP address to detect from which country the connection comes, with Cloudflare in front of your website, that IP will belong to one of our datacentre, and therefore be marked as coming from the US. So, yes, this will affect the current behaviour.

However, you can block countries using the [CF-Connecting-IP](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-Cloudflare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-) or the [CF-IPCountry](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168236-What-does-Cloudflare-IP-Geolocation-do-) header.

Answer (score 1):

I think it unblocks previously set countries, I am not sure. If it does, you can again block those countries using Cloudflare. Check [this](http://nginxlibrary.com/using-cloudflare-for-country-blocking/) out.

Comment: Please provide more than just a link. Explain what to do to answer the question fully.

Comment: Go on use cloudflare. If you keep geeting visitors from the unwanted country then block those countries (using the country code) after enabling the IP geolocation service as described in the link